# Create column with boolean values based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a DataFrame which contains rows of orders from customers. I want to create a column which returns True or False values when the customer has ordered twice before. So the third time they make an order, the column 'Recurring Customer' gets a True value.

The DataFrame looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
          'customer_id': ['5257', '8034', '21474', '21474', '21474', '6157']
})
```

The desired output should look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
          'customer_id': ['5257', '8034', '21474', '21474', '21474', '6157'],
          'recurring_customer: ['False', 'False', 'False', 'True', 'False]
})
```

I guess I have to use the np.where function but I don't know how to use it with unique and non-unique values. Could you help me with the last bit?

```
df['recurring_customer'] = np.where(df['customer_id']
```

Comment: If the same customer orders a third, fourth, fifth time?

Comment: @corralien when a customer orders more then 3 times the desired output is still True

Comment: @corralien shouldn't it be

`df['recurring_customer'] = df.groupby('customer_id').cumcount() >= 3` 

Because I want to a True value on the third order. Doesn't give '>= 2' the second order a True value?

Comment: 2 is the third order because the cumulative count starts from 0 (0, 1, 2 <- 2 is the third order)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `groupby_cumcount`:

```
df['recurring_customer'] = df.groupby('customer_id').cumcount() >= 2  # or == 2?
print(df)

# Output:
  customer_id  recurring_customer
0        5257               False
1        8034               False
2       21474               False
3       21474               False
4       21474                True
5        6157               False
```